# Returning string value in php array

Tags: php, arrays, string, return, echo

Its a simple problem but i dont remember how to solve it

i have this array:

```
$this->name = array('Daniel','Leinad','Leonard');
```

So i make a foreach on it, to return an array

```
foreach ($this->name as $names){
                echo $names[0];                 
            }
```

It returns

```
DLL
```

It returns the first letter from my strings in array.I would like to return the first value that is `'Daniel'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one :

```
foreach ($this->name as $names){
        echo $names;  //Daniel in first iteration 
        //  echo $names[0]; will print 'D' in first iteration which is first character of 'Daniel'           
  }



echo  $this->name[0];// gives only 'Daniel' which is the first value of array
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your loop, each entry in `$this->name` is now `$names`. So if you use `echo $names;` inside the loop, you'll print each name in turn. To get the first item in the array, instead of the loop use `$this->name[0]`.

Edit: Maybe it makes sense to use more descriptive names for your variables. 
For example `$this->names_array` and `foreach ( $this->names_array as $current_name )` makes it clearer what you are doing.

Comment: `I would like to return the first value that is 'Daniel'`

Answer (score 0):

Additional answer concerning your results :

You're getting the first letters of all entries, actually, because using a string as an array, like you do, allows you to browse its characters. In your case, character 0.

Use your iterative element to get the complete string everytime, the alias you created after `as`.
If you only want the first element, do use a browsing loop, just do `$this->name[0]`. Some references :

- http://php.net/manual/fr/control-structures.foreach.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/fr/language.types.array.php